# Is library dependency problems can be avoided with interfaces

Tags: c++, makefile

Today I learned something new about library dependencies from one of my collages and I want to be sure it is correct.

So normally if a library depends(libB.a) on the other one(libA.a) 
than in the make file order should be -lB -lA as far as I know. The lowest level library(the library which other libraries depends on) should be in the end of the -l list.

I have been told today if the dependency of libB to libA is an interface  than the order does not matters. I have been explained since this dependency will be resolved in the run time, in linking stage compiler does not needs any machine code information from libA. Using symbols from header file will be enough.

I wanted to confirm if I understand what I have been told correctly? Is it correct linking library order does not matters in case of usage of interfaces. If correct is it compiler depended or specified in language itself?

Also what have been told makes sense when thinking about dynamic linking but than how come the object inside of libA could be created without the actual machine code?

I hope I explained my point enough if not I can try to make a sample code.

Comment: What do you mean by "an interface"?

Comment: That is a good question which also makes me suspicious about what I have told. Since unlike many languages C++ does not have interfaces all we have is Pure Abstract Classes.

Comment: For binary compatibility there's something like COM from MS or iBCS from Intel needed. Because between different compilers (or versions of the same) there's no gurantee that everything works the same way. Also keep in mind that there could and will be different runtimes and different versions from the STL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, order is *only* important for resolving dependencies in *static* libraries and objects (well, including "main" object too) with GNU `ld` linker (or similar). That's because `ld` scans that list only once from left to right "forgetting" every symbol which wasn't referenced so far. BTW. Such behaviour may be modified by using `-Wl,-u,sym` linker option, which forces `ld` to create a reference to a `sym` before scanning. (Although it's not of much use if libB.a needs more than a dozen of symbols from libA.a).

However, all said applies to neither (1) some other linkers (if they keep tracking all symbols, no matter what the order is); nor (2) dependencies between shared libraries / DLLs (because it's job for OS loader, not for linker); nor (3) run-time dynamic linking using `dlsym()`, `GetProcAddress()`, etc. (well, obviously, linker knows nothing of it); nor (4) libraries exposing "a flexible interface", such as Microsoft COM, which is essentially a mix of run-time dynamic linking and ["factory pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).